# Get rows where one column is unique and another column is the lowest value relative to the unique column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am struggling with a relatively simple problem but just cant get my head around it.

I have a method `getNextRound()` which returns an array of numbers. The numbers represents the week numbers in the db table.

I then have a second method `getUpcomingGames()` where I call the the first method I then want to use the numbers from the first method to use in my query.

**Here is an example: METHOD 1**

```
public function getNextRound(){

        $sql = "SELECT min(weekNum) from schedule WHERE schedule.gameDateTime > NOW() GROUP BY tournament ORDER BY gameDateTime ASC";
        $stmnt = $this->db->query($sql);
        if ($stmnt->num_rows() > 0) {
            print_r($stmnt->result());
            return $stmnt->result();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

**RESULT FROM ABOVE METHOD / QUERY**

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[24]
      public 'min(weekNum)' => string '38' (length=2)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[25]
      public 'min(weekNum)' => string '14' (length=2)
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[26]
      public 'min(weekNum)' => string '7' (length=1)
```

I now want to use the data in the array to get all info contained in schedule table related to the week number.

**My problem is here**

METHOD 2

```
public function getUpcomingGames()
    {
//HERE I WANT TO GET ALL INFO FROM SCHEDULE WHERE ROUND = $week
        $rounds[] = $this->getNextRound();
        foreach ($rounds as $round) {
            $sql = "SELECT *  from  schedule WHERE weekNum = '$round' ORDER BY gameDateTime ASC ";
            $data[] = $this->db->query($sql);
            var_dump($data);
        }
```

ERROR: Among others I get an array to string conversion error.

I have looked through the codeigniter docs, but could not find the method which I am looking for.

DB TABLE
[image: qu]

**QUESTION:**

- Is there a query method in CI where I can insert an array into a query and loop over array (), if that makes sense?
- How can I improve / fix the above query?

Comment: Use IN QUERY in second-one

Comment: Should I keep the `foreach()` loop?

Comment: No need then to use `foreach()`. but compare result after using `IN` that it's giving same result what you are getting now or not?

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee Do you _actually_ need both of these methods or are you happy for them to be merged into one elegant method?

Comment: The `tournament` column is not included in your screenshot.  You have not supplied a complete schema.  Your second query attempt "un-relates" `tournament` and `weekNum` -- this means that all of the answers below are doomed to be inaccurate and you need to completely rethink your approach.  Until then, you will be generating result sets with weekNums from tournaments in the past.

Comment: This question **Needs More Clarity**.

Comment: @mickmackusa thank you for your feedback. I am busy working on the problem follwing given advice. I will update findings / question as I get closer to solution appropriately

Comment: You may temporarily remove/delete this question until it is reworked.  This way it is removed from the review pool and volunteers will not waste time on it.  I look forward to helping if you get stuck. @Tim  please include a dbfiddle link when you improve your question.

Comment: @Tim please make me a dbfiddle link so that I can have a play with your data from my phone.  Please include 20 records -- some that qualify and some that don't.

Comment: I may be completely wrong, but If I understand well, your getNextRound function returns an array of objects. So, when you do `foreach($rounds as $round)`, $round should contain the object and not the week number. It will explain the string conversion error. Did you try `$round->min(weekNum)`in your query ? (you should replace min(weekNum) by an alias in the original query, as I'm not sure the brackets are allowed in member name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you require a query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM schedule AS parent
JOIN (
    SELECT tournament,
           MIN(weekNum) AS nextWeek
    FROM schedule AS child
    WHERE gameDateTime > NOW()
    GROUP BY tournament
) ON parent.tournament = child.tournament AND parent.weekNum = child.nextWeek
ORDER BY gameDateTime";
```

This will maintain the relationship between tournaments and weekNums when passing qualifying rows to the parent query. This way the result set remains true even if you have a non-qualifying tournament with a qualifying WeekNum.

The codeigniter equivalent is:

```
$this->db->select('tournament, MIN(weekNum) AS nextWeek');
$this->db->from('schedule');
$this->db->where('gameDateTime >', 'NOW()', false);
$this->db->group_by('tournament');
$subquery = $this->db->get_compiled_select();


// $this->db->select('*'); <- not necessary
$this->db->from('schedule AS parent');
$this->db->join('(' . $subquery . ') AS child', 'parent.tournament = child.tournament AND parent.weekNum = child.nextWeek');
$this->db->order_by('gameDateTime');
return $this->db->get()->result();
```