# check if query builder already issued where or like?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, query-builder

I am so convenient using built-in codedigniter query builder.

I have to output searching to an existing page since that page involves multi-table.
Currently, I already have a lot of if there,

1. I am curious how to check if statement `db->where()` or `db->like()` have been called or not?
2. My second option is to construct new query that join 2 tables, but my table does not have any direct relationship, I try to use `$this->db->join()` it fails on the join condition. I am lack of example of using join, especially the join type. I am expecting to use something like

   SELECT * FROM p JOIN hs ON hs.id=%-`p.id`-%

I am already stuck here, and I am aware that the `db->get()` will erase the data filtering.
Any suggestion?

Comment: *"I am curious how to check if statement db->where() or db->like() have been called or not."* Do you mean like a `$db->hasWhereStatement()` method in the API

Comment: yeah, but I am sure codeigniter, especially v3. does not have that one.

Comment: You could write a class which extends the default query-builder one and make those functions

Comment: may be, you gather where and like in class properties and issue  needed them just before get

Comment: @RaymondNijland codeigniter query builder really can't be extended :(

Comment: You want to see the "compiled select"? If so, we have duplicates for that.

Comment: @mickmackusa after compiled yuo can't ask get

Comment: k, i get the idea, However, would you mind explaining it hard in the first place? I mean as an answer, Please take the credit :)

Comment: @splash58 that's news to me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62480330/2943403 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/61077697/2943403 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/60608429/2943403 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/61229709/2943403  Is one of us misunderstanding?

Comment: @Adi I think I would need more clarity before I ventured an answer.  Once you show us what might be in your compiled_select string, we might be able to suggest a dirty `strpos()`, `str_contains()`, or regex as a replacement for a proper sql parser.  Otherwise, you could go Raymond's path and extend something with in to allow you to dredge up private/protected properties/methods.

Comment: @mickmackusa as you see in that code after  `get_compiled_select` a code rebuild a query, because CI's builder reset all fields. In the case OP will be need to parse query to save only one where clause, what is not easy

Comment: Okay, it must be me who is confused.  I don't know what Adi needs and I can't follow what you are saying.  I'm out.  @spl

Comment: yep, and it's my bad. I already found the issue. and if someone explains *codeigniter query builder really can't be extended* it's kinda ok. I also find the easy way out to solve my need with manual query.

Comment: @mickmackusa knowing you as a meticulous researcher, I propose to look at the question, where I don’t even have hypotheses, except for the OP’s mistake  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71005419/issue-with-doing-an-array-multisort-sort-desc-i-m-duplicating-the-array#comment125521696_71005419